# Copy / paste on Windows 10 corrupts data by encoding first few characters

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm currently having an issue with copy / pasting on Windows corrupting data by encoding the first few characters.

For instance, let's say I have a file `test.txt` with content:

```
This is the content of a test file with some words and some letters. This is a second sentence with words.
```

If I copy / paste this file, the content end up being:

```
ÃJ8     J#K‘ÍÖg•Ã‘ÍÖj       j       j           ×ª  ome letters. This is a second sentence with words.
```

The result is always the same.

I tried on both my hard drives as well as using Powershell command `Copy-Item`:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\<me>\test.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\<me>\test-new.txt"
```

And it gives exactly the same result. It seems that this applies to all kinds of files since copy / pasting some files (JPG, RAR) result in an error opening them.

I didn't have the issue before, it apparently occured some days ago. Do you have any idea what could be causing this? Or how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Code page should match your locale so you can check it as well as registry.

for example, on my machine(UK locale), code page is 850 (for Western Europe):

```
>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

also registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
```

Value for OEMCP key in my case is 65001 (which is UTF-8).

There in the registry, you can change it permanently should need be (requires restart).

and also

the bottom status bar in the code editor, for example, VsCode:
in my experience sometimes without my intervention changes to BOM, hence weird characters appear. Please change it to UTF-8. Registry, code page and watching status bar in the editors solve problem in most cases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer me! I ended up restoring my system completely using the restoration tool to a point about three weeks ago and that "fixed" the issue, though I could not figure out how exactly it appeared. I think your answer is likely to be on spot, if the issue reappears I'll be sure to try it! :)